# Artifactory - Migrate from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: apache, https, artifactory

The following are steps that I executed:

1. Created CSR using https://www.digicert.com/easy-csr/openssl.htm
2. Obtained CA certificate & Certificate chain in pem format
3. Modified files for HTTPS implementation: httpd.conf, ssl.conf, server.xml
4. I put the certificate & key in /etc/httpd/certificates:
   armdev.key certnew.cer certnew-chain.crt
5. stop/start apache and artifactory service
6. launch https://arm.cn.ca:8443/artifactory. Errors:

   IE error: "This page can not be displayed".

   Chrome error: "This site can not be reached".

JFrog instruction to configure Artifactory behind Apache is not clear. Could you help please.

Comment: non-ssl version is also not working so it seems is only a certificate issue

Comment: I configured only for HTTPS, but HTTP is still working:
http://armdev.cn.ca:8081/artifactory/webapp/#/home

Comment: without your relevant apache httpd configuration and more info from log files it is impossible to answer this question

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Artifactory [reverse proxy configuration generator](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+a+Reverse+Proxy) in order to create the Apache configuration.
Using the generator you can fill in a set of fields to generate the required configuration snippet which you can then download and install directly in the corresponding directory of your reverse proxy server.

Comment: @TamNgoc I have reviewed your config. why do you need SSL on both Apache and Tomcat?

Comment: drorb, I have put httpd.conf, ssl.conf and server.xml and all excecution steps in:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5qdSW0mXNGAYUVvZno3VGowV2c?usp=sharing

Let me know if you can access it. Many thanks.

Comment: I thought that I need SSL on both. Should I reverse the change that I made on Tomcat server.xml. What should be done correctly ?

Comment: Keep the default tomcat configuration with the http connector listening on 8081. Have Apache do the SSL and adapt your virtual host configuration to use http for communicating with tomcat. Or use the configuration generator I mentioned in my answer.